# Receive multiple messages in an Erlang process

Tags: erlang

I'm having trouble understanding how to receive multiple messages with an Erlang process. Here's what I tried in the shell:

```
1> GetMessage = spawn(fun() -> getMessage() end).
<0.252.0>
2> GetMessage ! msg.
Got a message
msg
3> GetMessage ! msg
msg
```

Code for `getMessage/0`:

```
getMessage() ->
  receive
    _ ->
      io:format("Got a message~n", [])
end.
```

How can I keep receiving messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, got it:

```
getMessage() ->
  receive
    _ ->
      io:format("Got a message~n", [])
      getMessage() % Add this line!
end.
```

You need to call the function again after receiving the message.